# Apache tomcat7 on ubuntu 14.04.1 getting 404 error for deployed war and 401 error for manager

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, ubuntu, war

I have deployed war on tomcat7 on ubuntu server. I successfully get the tomcat7 home page on hitting the ip:8080 link.

If that further helps, I have followed steps as given [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-7-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-apt-get).

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomcat7
```

So now tomcat7 is installed as a service.
To deploy war, I simply stopped tomcat and then placed the myapp.war file in the webapps directory. Then I started the tomcat server. The logs of catalina show these(skipping unnecessary lines):

```
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
May 12, 2015 3:44:01 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapp.war
May 12, 2015 3:44:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://www.springframework.org/tags is already defined
```

This gives me 404 error when I try to access ip:8080/myapp url.

I then tried to download windows binary for apache and then placed war in webapps then startup.bat(on another windows machine). This works perfectly(hence proving that there is nothing wrong with the war file and/or its web.xml). But only on linux this is giving 404 issue. I saw all the answers related to similar questions and most of them suggest accessing the manager app. So I installed manager app using sudo apt-get. It installed successfully. But unfortunately it shows up a username and password field on ip:8080/manager.
That requires the modification of tomcat-users.xml file and here is how mine looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<tomcat-users>
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary.
-->
<!--
  NOTE:  The sample user and role entries below are wrapped in a comment
  and thus are ignored when reading this file. Do not forget to remove
  <!.. ..> that surrounds them.
-->
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="role1"/>
  <user name="tomcat" password="s3cret" roles="standard,manager-gui,admin-gui,tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1"/>
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

I tried entering tomcat7 and s3cret as credentials, but that does not get accepted and again the box asking username and password pops up. I have no ideas as to why its happening. There seems nothing wrong from my end and since this is THE way to install tomcat and deploy war files(and its not the first time I am doing that), it should work for me as well.

Kindly someone provide guidelines to solve the same.

Comment: I think you should split your question into two, one for the app deploy and one for the manager. You will have better chances of getting good answers that way.

Comment: you should check the logs for the stacktrace / error message. /var/lib/tomcat7/logs/catalina.out

Comment: It seems the "standard" role is undefined...